# mailto command line not able to set additional parameters

Tags: command-line, email, microsoft-outlook, batch-file

I am trying to create a simple batch file to send an email. I am following steps found online and came up with a simple example like this:

```
START mailto:john@mail.com?cc=other@mail.com&subject=MySubject&body=MyBody
```

Running this does open a new email in Outlook with the proper TO and CC fields filled in, but Subject and Body are empty.

In the command window I get the following error output:

> 'subject' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. 
>   'body' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I can change the order of the arguments around, and what ever comes after the ? works, but everything after the & fails.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double quotes.

`START mailto:john@mail.com?cc=other@mail.com&subject=MySubject&body=MyBody`

becomes

`START mailto:"john@mail.com?cc=other@mail.com&subject=MySubject&body=MyBody"`

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand (&) is the character used to separate multiple statements on a single command line. `START` attempts (and succeeds) to run `mailto:john@mail.com?cc=other@mail.com` but then attempts to run "subject=MySubject" next and fails, hence the error message about subject not being recognized as a command.

I think "escaping" the ampersand with a carat will also work. For example:

```
START mailto:john@mail.com?cc=other@mail.com^&subject=MySubject^&body=MyBody
```